# Query regarding Tkinter(python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am creating a notepad using tkinter. I want whatever i write in the space provided by the TEXT widget stays inside the space and does not get deleted after i close it. I know how to save it into a text file but i want it to stay in the space provided by the TEXT widget after clicking on the button "save".

Here is the code

```
Label(root1,text="Welcome",fg="white",bg="red",font=(('cailbri'),20)).pack(fill=X)

    global hi
    hi = Text(root1)
    hi.pack(pady=20)


    Button(root1,text="Save",width=10,height=2,command=save).pack()
```

As you can see, when we run the code a tab with a blank space appears where we can write. I want, whatever i write in that space stays there everytime i open it.

Can anyone help me with this???

Comment: Why don't you write it to a file and read it every time then?

Comment: Well we do not see nothing, but we can assume that it happens this way, since your code isnt a minimal reproducable example of your code. Anyway, if you want to set a default text to your Text widget you can use `insert` for. If you want to save a information that was built while running your code, there is no way arround to save the information somewhere. Otherwise the information is lost after closing your program.

Comment: It's up to you to save the data on exit, and restore the data when the program starts up. There is no magic function to do that for you.,

Comment: @Atlas435  let me explain you the entire program, There is login window first at the beginning, whenever the user passes the login window another tab i.e the tab with the TEXT widget appears where you can write what you want say it can be passwords or anything. Now if i save it into a text file then it can be accessed by anyone so there is no use of the login window. I just want to the data to accessed only after someone has logged in using the correct credentials. This will not be possible if i save it into a text file.

Comment: You could write a script to encode and decode your information. So the password is just readable to your program. Again the information has to be saved somewhere because it is just temporary available. Or you can save it to a cloud, a server or something. There are no limits for saving the information